# error : lvalue required as increment operand

Tags: c++

following code giving this error :

```
int main()
{
    int i = 4, j=10;
    int k, l;

    k = ++ (++ i);
    l = (j++) ++;

    cout << "k : " << k << endl;
    cout << "l : " << l << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It will be very helpful, if anyone could explain why that error occurs.

Comment: I see college season has started again. Both lines are **undefined behavior**. But since you would never write code like this in real life why why why ask about. Don't write code like this.

Comment: @Loki One is just ill-formed. The other always used to be undefined behaviour, but I'm not certain it is now; the rules changed in C++11. I agree though that one should never do this.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `j++` is the old value of `j` rather than a reference to `j`. You can't apply another increment to it because you can't increment values.

Comment: (Whereas `++i` increments `i` and returns a reference to the variable itself so you can increment it again. But using multiple increment operators on the same thing can cause problems; it's really best not to.)

Comment: And this only holds for scalar types. If you write your own class and overload `operator++(int)`, `(j++)++;` can be legal.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you write `X ++`, X must be a variable, X must be the thing you are incrementing. So `(j++) ++` is an error because `(j++)` is not a variable. Just write `j += 2` instead.

Note to experienced programmers, I know this is a gross simplifcation.

Comment: Your post indirectly says `(++ i)` is a variable

Comment: @P0W How so? I only mentioned j++ not ++i.

Comment: @john Because `(++i)++` is not an error, and the only way you suggest this can be possible is if `++i` is a variable.

Comment: @GavinSmith Right, that's the gross simplification. I thought this was the simplest way to present what is quite an advanced topic, the details of which I doubt the OP is concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Just write j += 2. Why you're using the operator++ in a wrong way ? 
Apply KISS.